# My snake plant stopped growing

Tags: houseplants

I’ve had this plant for 6 months and in those 6 months three leave shot up like crazy! They grew over a foot in length but the rest of the leaves have all stayed the same length. Is this normal?[image]

Comment: That is beautiful plant, Listen to what @GardenGems is saying. Im having same issue with my plant in "https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/48773/dwarf-zeylanica-snake-sansevieria-trifasciata-no-pup"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, snake plants are loved because you can put them in some of the worse conditions and they remain the same.  Where many plants would fail in a entryway with very little real light a Sensevieria, snake plant will remain the same for many month, years, before showing any sign of stress.   The plant will also not change much in ideal conditions.  If it is growing at all it must be happy. Do not expect the older leaves to change very much.  They are what they are. Love them for their undying structure.